# how to use WHERE condition to find specific value from string in table?

Tags: php, mysql, regex

**NEED:**

I need to select extract value in the field using mysql. The value are separated by commas.

**MYSQL TABLE:**

```
id   |   city      |  cusine_type
------------------------------------
1    | Coimbatore  |  3 Star Hotel
2    | Coimbatore  |  5 Star Hotel, Bakery
3    | Coimbatore  |  3 Star Hotel, Ice Cream Store
4    | Coimbatore  |  Star Hotel, Restaurant
```

**MY PHP AND MYSQL CODE**

```
include "db.php";
$city='Coimbatore';
$cus_type='Star Hotel';
$qy=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM add_res where city='$city' and cusine_type REGEXP CONCAT(',?[$cus_type],?') ");
```

**PROBLEM:**

The above code select all the rows in a table. I need only row 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
cusine_type LIKE '%$cus_type%'
```

Edit based on your edited question. A good option is

```
FIND_IN_SET('$cus_type',cusine_type)
```

**[Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a0c8b/3)**

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?s=1|16.0977)

Comment: Sorry Friend. This code is not worked. When Using this code, no rows is fetched

Comment: But a couple of mins ago you said it was working perfectly. What's the error?

Comment: When adding a new cusine type "Start Hotel" its not working. It fetch all the rows.

Comment: can you give solution for below. 

`$cus_type=$_POST['cus_type'];
if($cus_type=='all')
{
$cus_type='*';
}
else
{
$cus_type=$_POST['cus_type']
}

include "db.php";
$ff=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM add_res where cusine_type=$cus_type");`

Comment: echo the constructed statement; you will probably see the problem.  One problem in the original query was the misunderstanding of what [] means in a REGEXP.